# Dealing with Notifications on API 10 in Android

Tags: android

The code i'm putting in `onCreate()` is the following:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
        notifApiGT10();
    else
        notifApiLT10();
```

Where,

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void notifApiGT10() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Notification.Builder builder ;
        NotificationManager notifier;
        builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setOngoing(true).setContentTitle("my Title").setContentText("my displayed text");

        notifier = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<=15)
            notifier.notify(1, builder.getNotification());
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15)
            notifier.notify(1, builder.build());
    }

private void notifApiLT10()
    {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentText("is actually in use")
        .setContentTitle("my Title")
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setTicker("my ticker")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Notification notif = builder.getNotification();
        NotificationManager mN = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mN.notify(1, notif);

    }
```

The above code is not working on API 10. My device is running Gingerbread and it's not working on it.
I wonder why...Any experts?

**SOLUTION**:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "my ticker", System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
Context context = getApplicationContext();
Intent i = new Intent(this,Main.class);
PendingIntent pd = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, null, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 


notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "my title", "my text", pendingintent);
NotificationManager mN = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mN.notify(1,notification);
```

The above solution solved my problem, 
even if you don't want to run anything on click, you should put the pendingintent inside the method setLatestEventInfo, but in pd as you noticed, in the 3rd field, i have set the intent to null

Comment: Why do you use `Notification.Builder` and `NotificationCompat.Builder`? `NotificationCompat.Builder` should work fine on AndroidApi > 10.

Comment: i know it's working fine on api>10 howevre it's no working on api <= 10

Comment: Oh, yes I remember, there as the problem, that API <= 10 need a pendingIntent, but > 10 not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using NotificationCompat.Builder.build()? [NotificationCompat.Builder.getNotification()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#getNotification%28%29) is deprecated.

FYI, last time I used NotificationCompat.Builder, setNumber() did not work properly and I ended up constructing Notification directly on older devices.

EDIT: Try using Notification class directly on older devices because [NotificationCompatImplBase](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.java#L85) (API <= 10) uses only 4 fields from the builder no matter how many are set.

Comment: Thank you Yuri! I used the Notification class but this time I put a PendingIntent pd instead of null. The problem was that I was putting a Null in the 4th field of Notification. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome William, glad it helped!  And thank you for up-voting my response :)